# Access Insert Where Key NOT in Other Table

Tags: ms-access

I have this query that is working OK

```
UPDATE Master SET [Date Closed] = Date()
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Extract
                  WHERE Master.Case = Extract.Case
                 );
```

Now I kind of want to do the opposite but can't get it to work.

ie I want to add data into Master table where the Case (Key) doesn't exist in Master BUT DOES exist in Extract.  I need the insert to copy the Case from Extract to Master tables with a couple of other fields called DFM and Clarification Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Master ( . . .)
    SELECT . . .
    FROM Extract e
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM Master m
                      WHERE m.Case = e.Case
                     );
```

I don't know the columns in the table, nor the values you want to set.